# how to join a table on a subquery that uses order by and limit

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlite

For each row from table tClass matching a given where clause,

join on the first row in tEv, sorted by time, where tEv.class_id = tClass.class_id

The following code throws the error
ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery

```
select
    c.class_id,
    c.class_name,
    e.start_time,
    e.ev_id
from
    tClass c 
    left join tEv e on (
        e.ev_id = ( 
            select
             ss1.ev_id 
            from (
                select 
                    ed.ev_id
                from
                    tEvDisp ed,
                    tEv e
                where
                        ed.class_id = c.class_id
                    and ed.viewable = 'Y'
                    and ed.display_until > localtimestamp
                    and e.ev_id = ed.ev_id
                order by
                    e.start_time
                ) ss1
            where
                rownum = 1
            )
        )
where
    c.is_matching = 'Y';
```

How can this be rewritten to do what is described?

The above is for oracle, but needs to work in sqlite (substituting where necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea about SQLite - that would need to be a separate question if this doesn't work - but for Oracle you could do something like this:

```
select c.class_id,
  c.class_name,
  e.start_time,
  e.ev_id
from tClass c 
left join (
  select class_id, ev_id, start_time
  from (
    select ed.class_id,
      ed.ev_id,
      e.start_time,
      row_number() over (partition by ed.class_id order by e.start_time) as rn
    from tEvDisp ed
    join tEv e on e.ev_id = ed.ev_id
    where ed.viewable = 'Y'
    and ed.display_until > localtimestamp
  )
  where rn = 1
) e on e.class_id = c.class_id
where c.is_matching = 'Y';
```

This uses a subquery which finds the most `tEv` data, using an analytic `row_number()` to identify the latest data for each `class_id`, which is restricted by the `rn = 1` filter.

That subquery, consisting of at most one row per `class_id`, is then used the left outer join against `tClass`.

Comment: This is great, thanks! 
As you say, won't work for sqlite, I'll need to find a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of construct should get you what you need.  You can fix the details.

```
select c.classid
, c.classname
, temp.maxstarttime

from tClass c left join (
select c.classid id
max(e.start_time) maxstarttime
from tClass join tEv on tEv.classId = tClass.ClassId
where whatever
group by c.classid) temp on c.classid = temp.id
```